# Window WF activity designer to toolbox

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I am trying to make an empty custom activity so that I can have comments in the workflow designer. I have an activity designer that does not do anything but has a text block so the comments can be added. What is the easiest way to get this into my workflow toolbox? I have an empty activity that is currently in the workflow toolbox, but I have no idea how to lay the new designer on top of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

attach the `Designer` attribute before your class declaration.

example code:

```
[Designer(typeof(CustomActityDesigner))]
public class CustomActivity:NativeActivity {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Designer attribute to attach the activity designer to the activity. When you drag the activity onto the designer you will get to see your designer instead of the default designer.